# Adding the same object to multiple to-many relationships

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

Have a core data question that I am trying to solve for the past couple of hours (5hrs).

I have two entities: Student and Class.

Student attributes: name, grade 
Class attributes: name

Relationships:

1. Student <<------>>Class, both have
   to-many relationship.
2. I create student 1.
3. Then create Class 1, Class 2.
4. I then add Student 1 to Class 1
5. I then add Student 1 to Class 2.

Now when I change the grade of student 1 via the Class 1 its also change the grade for Class 2. 
So how do I solve this problem. Thanks a bunch.

**UPDATE (1):**
According to answers, I have modeled the following:

[image]

I want to add the same student to different classes:
**So is the relationship between Student and Class right?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The complete answer*, thanks to all the comments above and also atomicbird #iphonedev irc channel:

To add the **same** student to **different** classes and **have or edit** the student's grade pertaining to each class: the model is:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create a new Class to hold the Grade for a Student and Grade.  Something like StudentClassGrade or whatever

Comment: thats whats I was thinking. Have an entity for Student Name and an entity for StudentGrade and an entity for Class. So relationships would be: studentName<-->>studentGrade and Class<<-->>studentName. does that seem right? also thanks for a very fast reply

Answer (score 1):

I would model it as

Grade:

- attribute: gradeValue (0-100)
- relationship: student

A Class contains a collection of these

- relationship: grades

it is highly suggested all relationships in core data have a reverse relationship, thus:

Grade:

- (reverse) relationship: class

Student:

- (reverse) relationship: grades

Of course, what's "forward" and what's "reverse" it purely semantics.

Comment: how about the relationship between class and student. Could  you check the update above, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I am assuming it right, for each class, student has a grade. If that is the case then you should have student_class and student_class_grade models. student_class ---one to many---student_class_grade.

Comment: I think it should be student_class <--one to many-->>student_class_grade